# Can I change the order of two key:value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I want to change the order in a dictionary of two key:values

The example is:

`dico = {'a': [0, 0, '-', 'b'], 'b': [0, 0, 'c', 'd'], 'c': [1, 0, 'a', 'b'], 'd': [0, 0, 'c', '-']}`

I want to change the order between the key 'b' and 'c' like this:

`dico = {'a': [0, 0, '-', 'b'], 'c': [1, 0, 'a', 'b'], 'b': [0, 0, 'c', 'd'], 'd': [0, 0, 'c', '-']}`

I don't wanna use any method or function like (sorted etc...)

If you know how to do, it would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to change the order? it has little meaning in a dictionary

Comment: There is *no* point to do that - if you understand that dict *key* is unordered (well, expect the insertion order). So not sure what's the Use Case?  If you really insist so - just recreate a new dict then.

Comment: Why don't you want to use "any method or function"? What do you mean by that anyway? Are you including magic methods like `__getitem__` for example? (i.e. methods that are called implicitly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example dictionary data in Python language, you should change the position of two keys `‘b’` and `‘c’`. However, in dictionary type, keys cannot change directly. Using `keys()` function and `list()` function, you have to make another list data named `keys` which consists of every key in `dico` dictionary data. As Python language counts indices on the zero-based, the first key should be `‘c’` and the second key should be `‘b’`. Next, use a `for` loop to reflect the original values of `dico` dictionary data.

The following source code in Python language is an example for a suggestion. I hope it’ll work well for you.

```
dico = {'a': [0, 0, '-', 'b'], 'b': [0, 0, 'c', 'd'], 'c': [1, 0, 'a', 'b'], 'd': [0, 0, 'c', '-']}

keys = list(dico.keys())
keys[1] = 'c'
keys[2] = 'b'

for k in keys:
    dico[k] = dico.pop(k)

print(dico)
```

Comment: You’re welcome. 
Actually, I’ve been hesitating to write this code because it has several built-in functions in Python programming language. In the end, I suggested like this after I had come up with the way to inevitably use more basic functions/methods than the one example you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are stored in dict in insertion order.

If you really want to you can re-order all keys like this:

```
key_order = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
dico = {k : dico[k] for k in key_order}
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but it doesn't adhere to OP's condition of "don't wanna use any method or function" since it implicitly uses the `dict.__getitem__` method.

Comment: on the other hand you cannot interact with the dictionary without functions as it's not an indexable structure / not supposed to be sorted